# Using Multiple models with Class Based Views and pagination

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have 2 models Categories and Products.

A Category have multiple products and a Product can be in multiple categories.
A Category has a FK to itself.

```
`class Product(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='products')

class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='parent category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`
```

For a template I need:

- the category data and its children/subcategories data
- The products in the category and subcategories
- Pagination of products

I'm using Class Based Views, and I don't know which to use as `model` attribute for the class,because:

- if I use Category a I don't know how to set Pagination by Product and not by Category
- if I use Product, I need to get the category slug/id from url and filter Product queryset by category and also pass them to context
- if I use a RawQuerySet I get an error `RawQuerySet' has no len()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set your model to `Product` since that's the one you're essentially viewing and paginating on. Your view class should look something like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41297420/769971

Models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='products')

class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='parent category', related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You'll need to change your `get_queryset` to filter off of the category PK as well. Here's what I think it should look like:

```
def get_children_recursive(parent_category):
    children = parent_category.children.all()  # This depends on adding related_name to Category
    for child in children:
        children += get_children_recursive(child)
    return children

class ProductListView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'templates/your_product_view.html'
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'products'

    def get_queryset(self):
        category = Category.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['category_id'])
        all_children = get_children_recursive(category)
        return Product.objects.filter(categories=all_children)
```

`category_id` should come from the URL and should look something like this in your URLs file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^products/(?P<category_id>\d+)/$', ProductListView.as_view()),
)
```

Comment: the thing is, that category_id from kwargs is not enough, because I need also the subcategories id and besides in url I have slug/ so I need ids and have only one slug; another thing is that I need also category/subcategories data in context, and calling them in queryset and then in context creates duplicate

Comment: Added an edit that should address your issue. Completely untested, so you may have to work through a minor typo/bug here and there. Please note the change to the `Category` model which would allow pulling children.